# how to change the default logo through module in odoo 9

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo-9

I tried to change the logo of odoo , when install my costume module . Means whatever logo i will provide that will replace the default logo . so i try to override , also the controller is executing but result is not shown . no error will be generate . below code is my controller code .

main.py

```
class Extension(main.Binary):

@http.route([
    '/demo_theme/extension/company_logo',
    '/logo',
    '/logo.png',
], type='http', auth="none", cors="*")
def company_logo(self, dbname=None, **kw):
    imgname = 'logo'
    imgext = '.png'
    placeholder = functools.partial(get_resource_path, 'demo_theme', 'static', 'src', 'img')
    uid = None
    if request.session.db:
        dbname = request.session.db
        uid = request.session.uid
    elif dbname is None:
        dbname = db_monodb()

    if not uid:
        uid = openerp.SUPERUSER_ID

    if not dbname:
        response = http.send_file(placeholder(imgname + imgext))
    else:
        try:
            # create an empty registry
            registry = openerp.modules.registry.Registry(dbname)
            with registry.cursor() as cr:
                cr.execute("""SELECT c.logo_web, c.write_date
                                FROM res_users u
                           LEFT JOIN res_company c
                                  ON c.id = u.company_id
                               WHERE u.id = %s
                           """, (uid,))
                row = cr.fetchone()
                if row and row[0]:
                    image_base64 = str(row[0]).decode('base64')
                    image_data = StringIO(image_base64)
                    imgext = '.' + (imghdr.what(None, h=image_base64) or 'png')
                    response = http.send_file(image_data, filename=imgname + imgext, mtime=row[1])
                else:
                    response = http.send_file(placeholder('nologo.png'))
        except Exception:
            response = http.send_file(placeholder(imgname + imgext))

    return response
```

and i call this controller in my .xml file

```
<img src='/demo_theme/extension/company_logo'/>
```

But, the image is not replaced . so anyone have any idea please share with me .

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

yes, i got the answer , you should override the update_logo() method in weblient.js

.js file

```
var WebClient = require('web.WebClient');

WebClient.include({
 update_logo: function() {
    var company = session.company_id;
    var img = session.url('/demo_theme/extension/company_logo' + '?db=' + session.db + (company ? '&company=' + company : ''));
    this.$('.oe_logo img').attr('src', '').attr('src', img);
    this.$('.oe_logo_edit').toggleClass('oe_logo_edit_admin', session.uid === 1);
  },
});
```

Just change the path of controller .

Comment: ok good job you can costum the designe of the pages in the template if you want to hide some text or show other text

Answer (score 0):

try http://127.0.0.1:8069/logo  if the logo is shown that's mean you overrid is correct if not that mean you method is not working and use some print'message' to see if it's calling you method instead of the original

and check that you imported your py file in the **init**.py file

Comment: Thanx @Charif  for your reply , i just follow the above and the default logo is showing . but in login page , the logo is not sowing . so just suggest me how to solve this .

Comment: try http://127.0.0.1:8069/logo and got my log , also the controller was override , when i change the path in inspect so i can get the logo , but the path was not override .  <img src='/demo_theme/extension/company_logo'/> is not override on <img src='/web/binary/company_logo'/> . i have no idea , what am i do ?

Comment: the logo in the login page is comming from the  template in the web module you have to search for it if you are good in Qweb you can overrid it pyh Xpath expression if you are not search for it  the template are in the web module  :      <template id="web.layout" name="Web layout">       <template id="web.login_layout" name="Login Layout">     this two template are the design edit them by Qweb or directly and upgrade you web module

Comment: Thanx@Charif for your suggetion , as per your suggetion and my hard work solve my problem . just on thing are there you should override update_logo() method of webclient.js and give there your controller path . problem will be solve .

Comment: how to overrid the java script method by Qweb or manualy  edit you answer and show us how

Comment: You don't need Qweb , you can override manualy also . I posted my answer please look up this .